# Mockito shorten string representation of byte array

Tags: mockito

I need to verify that someMethod was called with "someArg", but I dont care about the second argument.

```
verify(mock).someMethod(eq("someArg"), anyByteArray)
```

, where `anyByteArray` is a custom matcher that matches any byte array.

Works, but, if the test fails, mockito prints the whole contents of the byteArray, something like this:

```
> org.mockito.exceptions.verification.VerificationInOrderFailure:

Verification in order failure
Wanted but not invoked:
store.saveData(
    "test",
    "test2",
    Matches any byte[]
);
-> at [...]
Wanted anywhere AFTER following interaction:
store.saveData(
    "test0",
    "test1",,
    [(byte) 0x7B, (byte) 0x0A, //// biiiiiiiiiiig array]
)
```

Is there a way I can make mockito somehow shorten the output of the huge array?

Comment: I think that's handled by the `toString` of your custom matcher.

Comment: @tgdavies doesnt seem to be, toString() of the matcher has no access to the argument..

Comment: maybe you have a use case for ArgumentCaptor? https://www.baeldung.com/mockito-argumentcaptor